# Webservices in Asp.net

Tags: c#, xml, web-services

I have the following webmethod in my application

```
[WebMethod]
public bool Test(string id)
{
    return true;
}
```

using WebRequest.Create(..) I get the following xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<boolean xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">true</boolean>
```

and using the following code

```
 XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(bool));
 var result = (bool)ser.Deserialize(responseStream);
```

I get the following exception

- "There is an error in XML document (2, 2)."
- `<boolean xmlns='http://tempuri.org/'> was not expected.`

Comment: a `XmlSerializer` of type `bool` returns an xml something like `<?xml version="1.0"?><boolean>true</boolean>` when serialized.

Comment: I realized that, but that doesn't really help me to deserialize the data returned from the webservice

Comment: I guess that's some sort of namespace associated with the webservice.

Comment: Think I have it :) thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it working by doing the following

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T), "http://tempuri.org/");
```